# Docker Pull - failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF

Tags: macos, docker

Attempts to pull (`docker pull <image>`) large Docker images (over 3 GB), e.g.:

- blang/latex:ctanfull; or
- sumdoc/texlive-2017;

end on MacBook Pro (16GB RAM, macOS High Sierra, Docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac49) with message: `failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF`. Pulling smaller images (under 2GB) works without any problems.

Command `docker image prune` and/or rebuilding Docker into factory settings didn't help. There seems to be no permissions issue of RAW file/folder.

(I can, however build these images with `docker build -t <> .` with no issues at all...)

Any ideas why `docker pull` command fails for large images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the succesful execution of the `tar` command in Docker is required sufficient temporary storage.

It can either be a SWAP or RAM.

Thus, the easiest way how to fix this issue is (temporary) increasing the RAM available to Docker in Preferences/Advanced setup of Docker to amount higher than is size of the repository (assuming you have enough RAM available).

Comment: this solved my problem. Thank you. In your Docker Desktop go to Settings>Resources>Advanced>Memory limit. I bump it up from 7 to 11, now the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

```
docker system prune -a
```

WARNING! This will remove:

- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all images without at least one container associated to them
- all build cache